# Can you have a different linux Desktop Environment for each user on one computer?

Tags: fedora

We currently have fedora 28 running on our family computer with the Cinnamon desktop environment. Unfortunately, multiple family members have different preferences in DE. Is it possible to have Cinnamon for one user and KDE for another user? How do you set this up?

Comment: Can't you just install all DE and select them through your Display Manager?

Comment: You can but then some components of different desktops seem to conflict. Is dual booting the only way to have the different DEs be completely distinct?

Comment: Use your distro package manager all the time, and tell people what's in conflict, that's your efforts, you should tell people.

Comment: Thank you. I know some of this has already been done. I'll try to add to the effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, easily. There is a little gear icon by the sign-in button on the login screen. Clicking that icon will let you select any of the installed desktop environments. The choice is remembered per-user.

Of course, you do need alternate desktop environments installed for this to work. Generally, you can install them from the command line using `dnf groupinstall`. Get the list of various possible groups with `dnf grouplist`. (Note that this doesn't necessarily work in reverse; removing a group you decide you don't want may remove things needed other groups.)

Comment: Thank you. I needed LXDE environment for one user to start Kodi for home entertainment.